# Nuxt with Javascript disabled gives no content

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

I created an app with NuxtJs, everything works well with javascript enabled on the browser but when I try to disable the javascript no content comes into the page.
Here is what the Inspect Network shows:

[image]

Is there any method to show a static website when the javascript is disabled, or any idea to avoid this problem?

Comment: The issue with your requirement is that nuxt is using javascript to render and load all the content. Which nuxt version do you use? This issue could solved by using SSR, so that the content will be prerendered on server and will be delivered to the client, without the need for JS to render it. But still, all interactive elements that need JavaScript still wouldn't work obviously.

Comment: Thank you for your reply,  I think I am using mode SSR on my website as it default on Nuxt.config.js, is it just like that, or I have to do something else? Thank you.